# Error when installing mysql on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, software-installation

I get This error when I try to install MySQL on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
[sudo] password for xxxxx:  
Reading package lists...  Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you're running?

Comment: Did you enabled the main repository?

Comment: That problem can occur when you are using an EOL release which means that the software sources for mysql has changed. The command is correct, https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/serverguide/mysql.html for the official documentation for 13.10.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` again.

Comment: i suppose it is varsion 11.04

Comment: Please update your system to 12.04 or 13.10 ;)